# ThreeJS: How to load a SVG file which has text in it

Tags: svg, three.js

I have an SVG file with some text content in three.js. when I try to load it using SVGLoader, it loader the SVG content but misses the text content while rendering. Is there any way to render the text content too in the scene and will it take the text's position and place the text in the correct position as in the file?
I have attached the SVG https://jsfiddle.net/keg59fur/

```
 <svg height="30" width="200">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">I love SVG!</text>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the SVG in this thread?

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/loaders/SVGLoader.js does not seem to support text elements

Comment: Sure @Mugen87 I have attached the SVG